# Showing that the number of positive entries of $n \times n$ matrix, $Bx$, is always larger than the number of positive elements in $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Context:**

Let $B$ be a primitive $n \times n$ matrix with positive diagonal entries. And let $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}$ be a non-negative vector with at least one zero entry.

**Question:**

Is is possible to show that the number of positive entries of $Bx$ is strictly larger than the number of positive entries of $x$?

Comment: @user1551 Updated the question; sorry about that notational error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because $x$ may be a positive vector and $Bx$ cannot possibly have more than $n$ positive entries.

The answer is affirmative, however, if the number of positive entries in $x$ is between $1$ and $n-1$. In this case, let $\mathcal I$ be the index set $\{i: x_i>0\}$. Since $B$ is primitive, it is irreducible. Therefore $b_{kl}>0$ for some $k\not\in\mathcal I$ and $l\in\mathcal I$. Now we have $(Bx)_i\ge b_{ii}x_i>0$ for each $i\in\mathcal I$ and $(Bx)_k\ge b_{kl}x_l>0$ as well. Therefore the number of positive elements in $Bx$ is at least $|\mathcal I|+1$.