# Showing that the product of $n-1$ primitive $n \times n$ matrices is always positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Context:**

Let $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_{n-1}$ be primitive $n \times n$ matrices with positive diagonal elements.

**Question**

Is it possible to show that $B_1B_2 \ldots B_{n-1}>0$?

I have found this to be true for up to $n = 4$, but I am not sure how to prove it for all values of $n>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasn't this been addressed by your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4570049)?

Denote by $\|\cdot\|_0$ the so-called $L_0$ norm, i.e., $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero elements in a vector $x$. Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

By the answer to your previous question, if $B$ is an $n\times n$ primitive matrix with a positive diagonal and $x$ is a vector such that $0<\|x\|_0<n$, then $\|x\|_0<\|Bx\|_0\le n$. Clearly, if $\|x\|_0=n$, we must have $\|Bx\|_0=n$.

It follows that $\|e_i\|_0,\|B_{n-1}e_i\|_0,\|B_{n-2}B_{n-1}e_i\|_0,\ldots,\|B_1B_2\cdots B_{n-2}B_{n-1}e_i\|_0$ is a sequence that keeps strictly increasing until it is stabilised at $n$.

Now, since this finite sequence has $n$ terms and the first term is equal to $1$, if the sequence has not yet been stabilised in the interim, then when the last term is reached, there should have been $n-1$ increments. Hence the last term must be equal to $n$ and $B_1B_2\cdots B_{n-2}B_{n-1}e_i$ is a positive vector. Since $i$ is arbitrary, $B_1B_2\cdots B_{n-2}B_{n-1}$ is a positive matrix.

(By the same reasoning, for each $k$ between $1$ and $n-1$, every column of $B_1B_2\cdots B_k$ will have at least $k+1$ positive entries.)

Comment: Should I delete this question or is it different enough from my other post that it can stay posted? I think these two different perspectives on the matter are both helpful. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MathIsHard I think you may just leave it here.